# Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float

Tags: captions, subfloats

I've got a custom command for placing pictures next to one another on the page, filling the width of the page, optionally with captions.

The code generated by the macro ends up looking like:

```tex
\begin{subfigure}{\imageAwidth\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
        %   \caption{1a}
%       \label{fig:sfig1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{\imageBwidth\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#2}
        %   \caption{1b}
%       \label{fig:sfig2}
    \end{subfigure}
```

Each time the macro is used, I end up with the error:

```
Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float.
```

Any idea what the problem going on is?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.

`subfigure` environments can only occur inside of `figure` environments